# How do I distributed a table using values from multiple columns?

Tags: postgresql, citus

Acording to [the Citus documentation](https://www.citusdata.com/docs/citus/5.0/dist_tables/append_distribution.html), it's easy to distribute a table using a single column:

```
SELECT master_create_distributed_table('github_events', 'created_at', 'append');
```

Is there a way to distribute a table using multiple columns? For example, something like:

```
SELECT master_create_distributed_table('github_events', 'user_id,site_id', 'append');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Distribution by more than one column is not supported in Citus. However, you can create a composite type and [partition your data by that composite type](https://gist.github.com/sumedhpathak/b8d4d46a656dbc58f364).

-- Content of link is inlined below in case the link goes dead --

## Steps for hash-partitioning on composite types

1. Create the type on the master and *all worker nodes*:

   ```sql
   CREATE TYPE new_composite_type as (project_key text, date text);
   ```
2. Create a function for checking equality, and associate it with the equality operator for the new type

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION equal_test_composite_type_function(new_composite_type, new_composite_type) RETURNS boolean
   AS 'select $1.project_key = $2.project_key AND $1.date = $2.date;'
   LANGUAGE SQL
   IMMUTABLE
   RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

   -- ... use that function to create a custom equality operator...
   CREATE OPERATOR = (
       LEFTARG = new_composite_type,
       RIGHTARG = new_composite_type,
       PROCEDURE = equal_test_composite_type_function,
       HASHES
   );
   ```
3. Create a new hash function.

   **Note:** This is just a simple example which may not provide a good even hash distribution. There are several examples of good hash functions which can be implemented in a separate C function instead of SQL.

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION new_composite_type_hash(new_composite_type) RETURNS int
   AS 'SELECT hashtext( ($1.project_key || $1.date)::text);'   
   LANGUAGE SQL
   IMMUTABLE
   RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
   ```
4. Define operator classes for the BTREE and HASH access methods:

   ```sql
   CREATE OPERATOR CLASS new_op_fam_btree_class
   DEFAULT FOR TYPE new_composite_type USING BTREE AS
   OPERATOR 3 = (new_composite_type, new_composite_type);

   CREATE OPERATOR CLASS new_op_fam_hash_class
   DEFAULT FOR TYPE new_composite_type USING HASH AS
   OPERATOR 1 = (new_composite_type, new_composite_type),
   FUNCTION 1 new_composite_type_hash(new_composite_type);
   ```
5. Create the table with the new type and distribute it.

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE composite_type_partitioned_table
   (
       id integer,
       composite_column new_composite_type
   );

   SELECT master_create_distributed_table('composite_type_partitioned_table','composite_column', 'hash');

   SELECT master_create_worker_shards('composite_type_partitioned_table', 4, 1);
   ```
6. Run INSERT's and SELECT's. Note that proper pruning will require the quoting as shown in those queries.

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO composite_type_partitioned_table VALUES  (1, '("key1","20160101")'::new_composite_type);
   INSERT INTO composite_type_partitioned_table VALUES  (2, '("key1","20160102")'::new_composite_type);
   INSERT INTO composite_type_partitioned_table VALUES  (3, '("key2","20160101")'::new_composite_type);
   INSERT INTO composite_type_partitioned_table VALUES  (4, '("key2","20160102")'::new_composite_type);

   SELECT * FROM composite_type_partitioned_table WHERE composite_column =  '("key1", "20160101")'::new_composite_type;

   UPDATE composite_type_partitioned_table SET id = 6 WHERE composite_column =  '("key2", "20160101")'::new_composite_type;

   SELECT * FROM composite_type_partitioned_table WHERE composite_column =  '("key2", "20160101")'::new_composite_type;
   ```

## Other notes:

There are two notes to be wary of:

1. Input file must be delimited properly to allow copy_to_distributed_table to work. To do this, use a `COPY (SELECT ()::composite_type_field, .... );` from normal table into a file and then load.
2. For pruning to work with select queries, the composite type field should be in quotes.